# Си AES и RSA шифрования

Tags: c, rsa, aes

Есть ли исходный код чтоб включить в проект, не подключая сторонние библиотеки. Есть открытые исходники у OpenSSL, но я пока что не соображу как достать именно эти методы из всего что там есть. Подскажите код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для AES исходников полно, начиная от исходной reference implementation, и заканчивая кучей разных библиотек. Ссылки удобнее всего брать из [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations) (как это ни пошло звучит), ну а вставить в свою программу проще всего именно reference. Для RSA выбор гораздо меньше, но тоже есть. Ссылки можно найти там же. Если пишете под Windows, то я бы посоветовал не брать исходники, а использовать CryptoAPI. Она сделана немного через заднее место, но все равно это проще, а главное в том, что функции CryptoAPI сертифицированы по FIPS 140-2. Для многих организаций это существенно. Для американских сертификация обязательное требование, да и для неамериканских это аргумент.